# How to set up factory in FactoryBot with has_many association

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many-through, factory-bot

Can someone tell me if I'm just going about the setup the wrong way?

I have the following models that have has_many.through associations:

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ... 

  has_many :listing_features
  has_many :features, :through => :listing_features

  validates_presence_of ...
  ...  
end


class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible ...

  validates_presence_of ...
  validates_uniqueness_of ...

  has_many :listing_features
  has_many :listings, :through => :listing_features
end


class ListingFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :feature_id, :listing_id

  belongs_to :feature  
  belongs_to :listing
end
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.rc4, FactoryGirl 2.0.2, factory_girl_rails 1.1.0, and rspec.  Here is my basic rspec rspec sanity check for the `:listing` factory:

```
it "creates a valid listing from factory" do
  Factory(:listing).should be_valid
end
```

Here is Factory(:listing)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :listing do
    headline    'headline'
    home_desc   'this is the home description'
    association :user, :factory => :user
    association :layout, :factory => :layout
    association :features, :factory => :feature
  end
end
```

The `:listing_feature` and `:feature` factories are similarly setup.
If the `association :features` line is commented out, then all my tests pass.
When it is

```
association :features, :factory => :feature
```

the error message is 
`undefined method 'each' for #<Feature>`  which I thought made sense to me because because `listing.features` returns an array.  So I changed it to

```
association :features, [:factory => :feature]
```

and the error I get now is `ArgumentError: Not registered: features`  Is it just not sensible to be generating factory objects this way, or what am I missing?  Thanks very much for any and all input!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Creating these kinds of associations requires using FactoryGirl's callbacks.

A perfect set of examples can be found here.

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/aint-no-calla-back-girl

To bring it home to your example.

```
Factory.define :listing_with_features, :parent => :listing do |listing|
  listing.after_create { |l| Factory(:feature, :listing => l)  }
  #or some for loop to generate X features
end
```

Comment: did you end up using association :features, [:factory => :feature]?

Answer (score 116):

Alternatively, you can use a block and skip the `association` keyword. This makes it possible to build objects without saving to the database (otherwise, a has_many association will save your records to the db, even if you use the `build` function instead of `create`).

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :listing_with_features, :parent => :listing do |listing|
    features { build_list :feature, 3 }
  end
end
```

Comment: This is the cat's meow.  The ability to both `build` and `create` makes it the most versatile pattern.  Then use this custom FG build strategy https://gist.github.com/Bartuz/74ee5834a36803d712b7 to `post nested_attributes_for` when testing controller actions that `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: upvoted, far more readable and versatile than the accepted answer IMO

Comment: As of FactoryBot 5, the `association` keyword uses the same build strategy for parent and child. So, it can build objects w/o saving to the database.

Answer (score 42):

You could use `trait`:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :listing do
    ...

    trait :with_features do
      features { build_list :feature, 3 }
    end
  end
end
```

With `callback`, if you need DB creation:

```
...

trait :with_features do
  after(:create) do |listing|
    create_list(:feature, 3, listing: listing)
  end
end
```

Use in your specs like this:

```
let(:listing) { create(:listing, :with_features) }
```

This will remove duplication in your factories and be more reusable.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits

Answer (score 20):

I tried a few different approaches and this is the one that worked most reliably for me (adapted to your case)

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    # some details
  end

  factory :layout do
    # some details
  end

  factory :feature do
    # some details
  end

  factory :listing do
    headline    'headline'
    home_desc   'this is the home description'
    association :user, factory: :user
    association :layout, factory: :layout
    after(:create) do |liztng|
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:feature, 1, listing: liztng)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Since FactoryBot v5, associations preserve build strategy. Associations are the best way to solve this and the [docs have good examples for it](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/893eb67bbbde9d7f482852cc5133b4ab57e34b97/GETTING_STARTED.md#has_many-associations):

```rb
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    title { "Through the Looking Glass" }
    user
  end

  factory :user do
    name { "Taylor Kim" }

    factory :user_with_posts do
      posts { [association(:post)] }
    end
  end
end
```

Or with control over the count:

```rb
    transient do
      posts_count { 5 }
    end

    posts do
      Array.new(posts_count) { association(:post) }
    end
```

Comment: As suggested by @sequielo below, I needed to use `[association(:post, user: instance)]` to avoid creating an additional post.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @thisismydesign, however it created an additional `post` on my end (FactoryBot v6.2).

To avoid this situation, I've added keyword `instance` as below:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :post do
    title { "Through the Looking Glass" }
    user
  end

  factory :user do
    name { "Taylor Kim" }

    factory :user_with_posts do
      posts { [association(:post, user: instance)] }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This solved it for me too. But what is "instance" and why is it needed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I set mine up:

```
# Model 1 PreferenceSet
class PreferenceSet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :preferences, dependent: :destroy
end

#Model 2 Preference

class Preference < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :preference_set
end



# factories/preference_set.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :preference_set do
    user factory: :user
    filter_name "market, filter_structure"

    factory :preference_set_with_preferences do
      after(:create) do |preference|
        create(:preference, preference_set: preference)
        create(:filter_structure_preference, preference_set: preference)
      end
    end
  end

end

# factories/preference.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :preference do |p|
    filter_name "market"
    filter_value "12"
  end

  factory :filter_structure_preference, parent: :preference do
    filter_name "structure"
    filter_value "7"
  end
end
```

And then in your tests you can do:

```
@preference_set = FactoryGirl.create(:preference_set_with_preferences)
```

Hope that helps.