# Rails 3 Factory Girl + Many to Many Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, factory-bot

There aren't currently any up to date answers for this using Factory Girl 4.1 (that I could find) - how do you setup a many to many relationship inside of a factory?

For instance I have **Students** and **Classrooms** which are in a many to many relationship using a join table, so far I had the following setup:

```
factory :classroom do
    name "Foo Class"
    ...
end

factory :student do
   name "John Doe"
   ...
end

factory :student_with_classroom, :parent => :student do
    after(:build) {|student| student.classrooms << classroom}
end
```

However this results in:

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `classroom' for #<FactoryGirl::SyntaxRunner>
```

My attempt was guesswork for the most part as I had no luck finding any non-deprecated syntax to accomplish this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create has\_and\_belongs\_to\_many associations in Factory girl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484374/how-to-create-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-in-factory-girl)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Actually I managed to find the answer I was looking for buried under a slew of other answers in this SO: [How to create has_and_belongs_to_many associations in Factory girl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484374/how-to-create-has-and-belongs-to-many-associations-in-factory-girl)

```
factory :classroom do
    name "Foo Class"
    ...
end

factory :student do
   name "John Doe"
   ...
end

factory :student_with_classroom, :parent => :student do
    classrooms {[FactoryGirl.create(:classroom)]}
end
```

Comment: I think the primary reason you can't just state the name of the factory is because it's expecting an array. Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

Check out this SO post: [How to set up factory in FactoryGirl with has_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963298/how-to-set-up-factory-in-factorygirl-with-has-many-association). It will point you to https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md; search for **has_many**.