# FactoryGirl - NoMethodError: undefined method `votes_count=' for #<PollItem:0xbd2c4814>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have two models, Poll and PollItem. I created for tests of this models factories:

I added next factories:

factories/polls.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :poll do

        question "What programming language are you using?"
        results_hidden 1
        from_date "2015-06-25 18:13:18"
        to_date "2015-07-25 18:13:18"

        trait :poll_item1 do
          association :poll_item,
          answer: "C#",
          votes_count: "1"
        end

        trait :poll_item2 do
          association :poll_item,
          answer: "Ruby",
          votes_count: "2"
        end
    end

  end
```

**factories/poll_items.rb**:

```
FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :poll_item do
      answer "MyString"
      votes_count "1"
    end
end
```

I run my spec test:

```
describe Poll do
  it "is invalid without a quation" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:poll, :poll_item1, :poll_item2).should_not be_valid
  end 
  it "does not allow duplicate poll_item per poll" do


  end 

end
```

When run i test, is displayed error -  NoMethodError: undefined method `votes_count=' for # ./spec/models/poll_spec.rb:5:in

Comment: Why your votes count is a string?

Comment: first time was integer. i replaced to integer again. same error

Comment: Was just asking. Keep it as an integer in any case. Do you have a migration to include votes_count field?

Comment: you are right. in migration poll_votes_count field. i changed. But now error: undefined method `poll_item=' for #<Poll:0xbcade348>.

Comment: Did you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963298/how-to-set-up-factory-in-factorygirl-with-has-many-association there are some quite good answers that should fit

Comment: i checked. cant undestand what wrong with my factory?